# Github gist editing without changing URL

Tags: javascript, url, github, edit

I have a gist with some javascript code in a `script` tag, like so:

```
<script src="https://raw.github.com/gist/b25dff23c2c4b4bd425a/f157aa95163311c4b58febb06b49ffd16419f642/images.js"></script>
```

And I will need to keep editing the JS file on github. However, when you edit a gist it changes the URL of the gist. How do I keep the same URL?

Comment: I don't think you can, it creates a new url everytime. If you have a repo you can just put a test folder there an load it from the repo.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Gist changed the path to this file pattern:

```
https://gist.github.com/<USER_NAME>/<GIST_ID>/raw/<GIST_REVISION_ID>/<GIST_FILE_NAME>
```

You will notice that now the top answers' links are 404'ing.

Simply apply this new pattern and voilà!

```
https://gist.github.com/<USER_NAME>/<GIST_ID>/raw/<GIST_FILE_NAME>
```

For instance:

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/wesbos/cd16b8b1815825f111a2/raw/lol.js

Comment: Don't be put off by the fact that the example link here results in a 404; that's because marclundgren has moved/removed/renamed his gist, not because the pattern doesn't work.

Comment: At first I thought that this answer wasn't working. After a little bit of waiting/experimentation, it seems that Github has some internal caching happening on this kind of Gist URL. It took 2-3 minutes for the changes to reflect in my browser, even when forcing a no-cache refresh.

Comment: The link, when it is without `gist_revsion_id` seems to be cached or just shows the first version forever? Can I achieve an effect where the link points to the latest version at all times?

Answer (score 18):

In case of gist,
`https://raw.github.com/gist/[gist_id]` OR
`https://gist.github.com/[user_name]/[gist_id]/raw`(which is more likely to be an unique URI.)
returns first file from the gist.

For gist with multiple files,
https://raw.github.com/gist/[gist_id]/[file_name]

The url works even when you change the filename.

e.g. https://raw.github.com/gist/4636655
https://raw.github.com/gist/4636655/imdb-getglue.js

Comment: The `https://raw.github.com/gist/[gist_id]` part doesn't seem to work anymore, at least if `gist_id` is the full SHA of the gist - it gives `400: invalid request`.

Answer (score 12):

Just add `/raw` to the end of your gist url.

```
https://gist.github.com/--user--/--id--/raw
```

This links to the latest revision of that file.

After updating the gist file, changes are reflected after a minute or two.

Comment: Easiest-to-remember answer I've yet seen.

Comment: This is the only suggestion on this entire page that worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can't change the content without submitting it (saving it) and that gives you a new URL.

If you want a link to something you will be constantly changing and have the URL always be the same, put it in a repo and save changes by committing it.

You'll end up with something like:

> https://raw.github.com/UserName/Repository/master/script.js

Comment: okay, so how does this repo thing work? I have https://github.com/OddLlama/images so how do I use it?

Comment: You clone it to your machine. Use either the app for mac or windows if you don't want to do it by command line.

Answer (score 3):

The other methods didn't work, so I'm using [`rawgit.com`](https://rawgit.com):

```
https://rawgit.com/<user>/<id>/raw/<file>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to remove your username from the url, if you want.

Take the url from the accepted answer above:

```
https://gist.github.com/<USER_NAME>/<GIST_ID>/raw/<GIST_FILE_NAME>
```

remove `<USER_NAME>` and move `raw` in front of `<GIST_ID>`, where the username was:

```
https://gist.github.com/raw/<GIST_ID>/<GIST_FILE_NAME>
```

But it doesn't work with RawGit.