# Is there a permalink to the latest version of gist files?

Tags: github, permalinks, gist

I created a gist with two files, the raw version of which I would like to use as a reference for an application which will query their contents. These contents will be updated on GitHub.

I found however that the URL of the file changes with each version of the gist. **Is there a permalink which would point to the latest version of a file in a gist?**

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/14529686

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Raw gist URLs follow the pattern below:

```
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/[gist username]/[gist ID]/raw/[gist commit ID]/[file name]
```

To view the latest version, simply remove the `[gist commit ID]` part:

```
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/[gist username]/[gist ID]/raw/[file name]
```

e.g.

```
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mwek/9962f97f3bde157fd5dbd2b5dd0ec3ca/raw/user.js
```

Keep in mind that the endpoint is cached, so your updates may be visible with a slight delay.

Comment: Do you know how long it will take for the cached version to be updated with the newest changes?

Comment: FWIW it looks like you can cache-bust by attaching a query string to the url, e.g. `https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mwek/9962f97f3bde157fd5dbd2b5dd0ec3ca/raw/user.js?cachebust=dkjflskjfldkf`

Comment: The file will (probably) be served with incorrect MIME type because of..human laziness.

Comment: Actually it seems that removing the end part also is needed, otherwise you might get old version of the file for some reason.. So it's:
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/[gist username]/[gist ID]/raw/

Comment: What user permission is required to do this?

Comment: @JustinThomas No permissions. It's public.

Comment: As mentioned by other users, I had to remove the filename as well, just ending with `raw` to get this to work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way is to just take the link of your gist and add `/raw` at the end of it.

The selected answer doesn't work as expected without removing the filename.